# @SerializedName not reflecting with Child class

Tags: java, gson, fasterxml

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class Parent {
    @SerializedName("home_town")
    private String homeTown;
    // getters & setters
}

class Child extends Parent {
}
```

when we check/print/log the **child** object it has something like:

```
{"homeTown":"blahblah"}
```

whereas our expectation is:

```
{"home_town":"blahblah"}
```

Now if we override the getter method of Parent class in Child class and annotate using `@JsonProperty("home_town")`, then it works

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

class Child extends Parent {
  @Override
  @JsonProperty("home_town")
  public String getHomeTown(){
    return super.getHomeTown();
  }
}
```

I had been expecting `@SerializedName` should have worked with Child class too in the first place through **inheritance**, I am little puzzled that why it worked only by overriding the getter method and annotating with `@JsonProperty`

Appreciate your help!

Comment: How are you serializing the object? Are you using GSON or Jackson? Please update the code in your question. `@SerializedName("home_town")` works perfectly fine for me when serializing child object using GSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it by using @JsonProperty on all getters in parent class like follows:

```
class Parent {
    @SerializedName("home_town")
    private String homeTown;
    // getters & setters

    @JsonProperty("home_town")
    public String getHomeTown(){
        return homeTown;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

This is how I've achieved my objective, this way I do not need to touch the Child class.